# Getting object from array of objects matching values inside and array of dates with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, lodash

i have an array of obejcts that has this structure

```
let events = [ {
  "initDate": "2019-11-20",
  "finalDate": "2019-11-22",
  "intermediateDates": [
    "2019-11-20",
    "2019-11-21"
  ],
  "priority": 1
},....]
```

So, i'm trying to get the object that matches from a given array of dates for example :

```
let filteredDays = [
  "2019-11-20",
  "2019-11-21",
  "2019-11-22"
]
```

i'm trying with lodash like this:

```
let eventsFound= [];
  let intersection = _.map( this.events,function(value){
    let inter = _.intersection(value.intermediateDates,filteredDates);
    console.log(inter);
    if(inter != []){
      foundEvents.push(value);
      return value;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
```

when i console log inter i get the first array with values then the next arrays are empty but it keeps pushing all the events into the foundEvents Array and the returned array is the same as the events array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're comparing two arrays using `!=`. In javascript `[] != []` is always true. To check if an array is empty, use `length` property like `arr.length == 0`.
2. Use `filter` instead of using `map` like a `forEach`.
3. To check existance use `some`/`includes` combo instead of looking for intersections.

So, filter events that some of its `intermediateDates` are included in `filteredDates`:

```
let eventsFound = _.filter(this.events, event =>
   _.some(event.intermediateDates, date =>
      _.includes(filteredDates, date)
   )
);
```

The same using native functions:

```
let eventsFound = this.events.filter(event =>
   event.intermediateDates.some(date =>
      filteredDates.includes(date)
   )
);
```

Comment: I only had to change the comparsion to arr.length, thanks for the help

Comment: @EduardoMoreno That should fix the comparison issue but there are still other issues with your code. My solution fixes them all. Anyways, you're welcome! I'm glad I could help! :)